# Why did Futures#successful require a dispatcher? (until Akka v2.0.2)

Tags: java, akka, future

Why do I need a dispatcher when I create a Future with a constant value? Isn't the value simply wrapped in a Future implementation? As I understand it, the future completes once the dispatcher can process another message that contains the constant value, but why would that be better than simply wrapping the value? This seems like unnecessary overhead to me.

*Update*: It seems as if this requirement was removed somewhere between Akka 2.0.2 and Akka 2.3.2. What changed? You can even see traces of this requirement in the current version's documentation. For example here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html - the executor service is not even used in the first code snippet anymore where it tries to show how to use them.

Comment: You don't. http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.2.3/akka/dispatch/Futures.html#successful(T)

Comment: That's wiered. I came from here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/java/typed-actors.html. Why did it do before? Also see here http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/dispatch/Futures$.html

Comment: Because that message dispatcher was used for executing the callbacks that were added to that promise. This was changed with SIP- 14